# Error al subir una imagen de gran tamaño con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Estoy usando PHP y SQL para subir imágenes a una base de datos, todo en localhost. Al subir imágenes de tamaño bastante reducido, se suben correctamente y las puedo visualizar correctamente. Pero al subir imágenes de tamaño superior a 1MB me sale este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\SRboots\editarperfil.php:69 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SRboots\editarperfil.php(69): PDO->query('INSERT into use...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SRboots\editarperfil.php on line 69

El código que uso para recibir la imagen y subirla a la base de datos es este:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) != null) {
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
        $insert = $conn->query("INSERT into users (image) VALUES ('$imgContent')");
        if ($insert) {
            $message = 'Dades actualitzades amb èxit';
        } else {
            $message = 'Dades actualitzades amb èxit';
        }
    }
}
```

Ya he probado de ajustar las configuraciones de php.ini y my.ini para que tengan tiempo y espacio para subir la imagen, dejando las configuraciones así.

**`my.ini`**:

```
 [mysqld]
    datadir=c:/xampp/mysql/data
    max_allowed_packet = 3000000
    innodb_log_file_size = 3000000
    innodb_page_size = 16K
    wait_timeout = 300
    [client]
```

**`php.ini`**: (las líneas que he modificado)

```
upload_max_filesize = 3M
post_max_size = 3M
max_execution_time=1200
```

Sin embargo, me sigue saliendo el mismo error y solo puedo subir imágenes con un tamaño muy reducido, no sé que más puedo probar.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Aumentar el tiempo máximo de ejecución en el archivo php.ini:

   `max_execution_time = 3000`
2. Verificar la configuración de timeouts en el código PHP:

   `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 3000);`
3. Aumentar el tiempo máximo de ejecución en el archivo php.ini:

   `$dbh = null;`
4. Aumentar el tiempo máximo de ejecución en el archivo php.ini:

   `$dbh->beginTransaction();`

   `...`

   `$dbh->commit();`

> También podrías agregar algunas validaciones antes de subir la imagen

1. Verificación de errores de subida de archivos:

   `if ($_FILES['image']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { throw new Exception('Error uploading file - error code ' . $_FILES['image']['error']); }`
2. Validación de tipos de archivo:

   `$allowedTypes = [IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF]; $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); if (!in_array($detectedType, $allowedTypes)) { throw new Exception('Invalid file type'); }`
3. Protección contra inyección SQL:

   `$imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into users (image) VALUES (:image)"); $stmt->bindParam(':image', $imgContent); $stmt->execute();`